# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Permission denied to access property "toString"

Tags: webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am using Selenium WebDriver to automate a page developed in angular framework. But when I run my tests on FirefoxDriver I am facing the below issue. The same code works perfectly on InternetExplorerDriver.

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Permission denied to access property "toString"
Command duration or timeout: 685 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b1534ae328c771e0856c93e187490ca824', time: '2016-03-15 10:43:46'
System info: host: 'L8WF0N72', ip: '30.142.97.71', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_77'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=true, rotatable=false, handlesAlerts=true, databaseEnabled=true, version=46.0.1, platform=WINDOWS, nativeEvents=false, acceptSslCerts=true, webStorageEnabled=true, locationContextEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: c35d9fb2-7697-4ecd-a7d5-0c8005182065
*** Element info: {Using=id, value=loginusername_txt_id}
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:363)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementById(RemoteWebDriver.java:413)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ById.findElement(By.java:218)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:355)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.findElement(ExpectedConditions.java:899)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.access$000(ExpectedConditions.java:41)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$7.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:205)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$7.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:201)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:238)
    at utilities.WebUtils.waitForElementVisible(WebUtils.java:23)
    at testCases.MenuOfResourcesTests.testSetUp(MenuOfResourcesTests.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:86)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:514)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:215)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:142)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:178)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:782)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:632)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:366)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:361)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:319)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:268)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1244)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1169)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1064)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:126)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:137)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:58)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Permission denied to access property "toString"
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b1534ae328c771e0856c93e187490ca824', time: '2016-03-15 10:43:46'
System info: host: 'L8WF0N72', ip: '30.142.97.71', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_77'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at <anonymous class>.patchEventTargetMethods/obj.addEventListener(https://va10dlvwbs302:9443/eea/app/common/lib/angular2/angular2-polyfills.js:1072)
```

Answer (score 3):

There has been a lot of back and forth between Angular and WebDriver communities on this defect. The below thread's would give you where the defect is currently residing.

[Github Issue Tracker](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2784)

The last comment on the defect is

> Angular 2 is patching EventTarget.prototype, so they are responsible for any bugs caused by their changes.
>
> This is not a Selenium issue, closing the bug.

So, i don't think there is a solution yet to this problem, but a few things that you can cross check is if you are using the latest selenium client library version and if the ff version you are using is as mentioned as supported by selenium folks

[Selenium WebDriver Supported Browsers and Versions](http://www.seleniumhq.org/about/platforms.jsp)